# How to run cucumber-gradle automation test script parrallely as well as in sequence manner?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, junit, cucumber

1. I am writing Web based application automation test script using cucumber,selenium webdriver, Java and gradle.
2. I have around some 25 feature files.
3. I need to test this 25 feature files parallel as well as in sequence manner.
4. Currently, I am running the one test at a time by using test name.
5. Is there any way to run the test in parallel as well as concurrent manner?

Comment: You can do by running two time but yes if you want to run on different browser then you should do some configuration at code level.

Comment: Why would you want to run cucumber scenarios in sequence? If you have dependencies between two different scenarios, then you are using a risky practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do parallel execution if you provide different cucumber runner classes.

Then you can configure the Test tasks in Gradle to run in parralel:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 4
}
```

And you need to define a test Task which executes your cucumber runners (in this example all have a Cucumber in their classname)

```
task cucumberTests(type: Test){ 
   includes = ['**/*Cucumber*'] 
}
```

Maybe this will help you

P.S. Regarding the sequential running: Cucumber doesn't guarante any running order of the different feature files

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using Maven, here is the example I used. Worked great for me!

https://opencredo.com/running-cucumber-jvm-tests-in-parallel/